# mysql group and count two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have no idea ho to group and count names in two columns in one table. Structure of my table is something like:

```
+------+-------------------+
| user | friend1 | friend2 |
+------+---------+---------+
|user1 | Adam    | Filip   | 
|user2 | Boris   | Norbert |
|user3 | Filip   | Carol   |
|user4 | Carol   | Filip   |
|user5 | Boris   | Patricia|
+------+---------+---------+
```

And I would like to get results as:

```
+----------+---+
| Filip    | 3 |
| Boris    | 2 |
| Carol    | 2 |
| Adam     | 1 |
| Norbert  | 1 |
| Patricia | 1 |
+----------+---+
```

It's ordered by count.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT friend1 AS friends, friend2 AS friends, COUNT(friends) AS friedscount FROM table GROUP BY friends ORDER BY friedscount DESC
```

Comment: @JohnWoo's solution is correct, but I'm wondering: in case you have a third friend, would you have to add a `friend3` column? Because that would be a bad design choice, in my opinion...

Comment: my users can only have two friends :-)

Comment: Poor, sad users :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

combine the rows first using `UNION ALL` to preserve duplicates inside a subquery then count

```
SELECT  friend, COUNT(*) friedscount 
FROM
        (
            SELECT  friend1 AS friend FROM TableName UNION ALL
            SELECT  friend2 AS friend FROM TableName
        ) a
GROUP   BY  friend
ORDER BY friedscount DESC
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd1a5e/1)